# C++ Gtkmm buttons onclick method blocks text change

Tags: c++, sockets, pthreads, gtkmm

So I have a Gtkmm Application, which should listen for the next connection requests and change the text of another Gtk Widget `status` to "Listening...", as soon as the user clicks a button.

The buttons onclick method looks as the following:

```
status.set_text("Listening...");

if(nh.listen()<0){
      status.set_text("Not connected.");
      return;
}
status.set_text("Connected");
```

Where `nh.listen()` is a blocking method which first binds the socket, then listens and accepts an incoming connection:

```
soc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);


struct sockaddr_in local_addr;

memset(&local_addr, 0, sizeof(local_addr));
local_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
local_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
local_addr.sin_port = htons(6666);

if(bind(soc, (struct sockaddr*) &local_addr, sizeof(local_addr))<0){
    return -1;
}

if(::listen( soc , 1) == -1){
    return -1;
}

struct sockaddr_in client;
socklen_t size = sizeof(client);
int socket_accept = ::accept(soc, (struct sockaddr*) &client, &size);

soc = socket_accept;
return 0;
```

The behavior I'd expect is that the text of `status` widget gets changed before `nh.listen()` is called and blocking the thread, but instead the thread gets just blocked.

Now my assumption is that the onclick method somehow blocks all other calls/changes of Gtk widgets and I'm wondering how I'd be able to achieve the desired behavior.

---- Edit ------

Considering @Ted Lyngmo 's comment I restructured the code as follows:

```
 void frame::onclick_listen(){
     std::thread listening_thread(&frame::listening_thread_fun, this);
     status.set_text("Listening...");
     listening_thread.join();
  }




 void frame::listening_thread_fun(){
      if(nh.listen()<0){
            //Error   
            status.set_text("Not connected.");
            return;
      }
      status.set_text("Connected");
 }
```

But nothing really changes. Since the connection is needed in order to continue I called the thread join() just after the text-change. Which means that the onclick method is still in scope when I try to change the text and thus probably blocking it. So what would be the best practice for the call of join()?

Comment: I don't know much about GTK but you should generally don't do time consuming work in GUI event handlers, like waiting for incomming connections on sockets. Create a thread for things like that.

Comment: But launching a thread and just after that waiting for it to finish will not add any paralellism to your program: you are still waiting fo the network!

Comment: @rodrigo Of course. The result from the thread needs to be synchronized into the main flow somehow. GTK may even have some built-in mechanism for doing just that, start a task and let the result be signaled back, whenever the task is finished.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Indeed, GTK uses Glib, and Glib has that GIO to do fully asynchronous network. I'm not too familiar with GTKmm, but I bet there is a GIOmm somewhere...

Comment: @Flo The new codes `listening_thread.join();` willl still block the event handler from returning until there's a connection. Look for support for asynchronous operations in GTKmm as rodrigo says.

Comment: Perhaps [29.3. Example](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/unstable/gtkmm-tutorial.html) is a good place to start.